# Phonegap open file dialog choose activity

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, android-activity

I have phonegap app. I want that choose file dialog would allow me to **choose activity**, like camera or documens.
[image]

With my current settings it will only open `Documents` activity to pick files from.

[image]

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: what about implementing the dialogs plugin and set up two buttons for that. The user can choose than what to open. Documents or Images.

Comment: i just want to choose file like i do in chrome browser. And there its allowing me to select activity.

Comment: What do you mean with "activity"? The source where you want to select files from like camera or documents or sth else?

Comment: Yes...the source. If im not wrong its called Content providers.

Comment: Yes and why don't you do it than like i described? Just give the user the option to choose from where to pic the files with the dialogs plugin and run your function after the users choice.

Comment: I want to take picture immediately when open dialog. Not take picture and then choose existing.